# Could red/green colour-blindness prevent you from taking a culinary job on a ship?

Tags: job-search, applications

I wish to take a culinary job on a cruise ship.

I am concerned that I might be rejected because I have red/green colour blindness.

Is this a valid concern, and if so is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Slack given.

Answer (score 13):

Being colorblind would rule you out of any crew position in the maritime world, the medical requirements for any position classed as a "Seafarer" are the same, and include the colorvision aspect. A "Seafarer" as per the Maritime Labour Convention is defined as:

> A seafarer is any person, including a master, who is employed or engaged or works in any capacity on board a ship and whose normal place of work is on a ship.

Would seem to indicate that yes, someone in a culinary position whose "normal place of work" was a ship would count as a Seafarer and therefore be subject to the same medical requirements as anyone else on the crew and thus the requirement regarding not being colorblind would apply.

All is not lost however since for those working in the hospitality-type areas if you fail the colorvision part of the test but are otherwise passed "fit" then  you can be issued an ENG1 certificate with the restriction **‘not fit for lookout duties’**. Such a certificate means you *can* technically do things like being a chef and it will then be up to the company operating the ship whether they accept candidates who have this exclusion.

**NB:** The colorblindness exclusion for crew relates to being able to correctly interpret various maritime signals that frequently use red and green as differentiators - hence the "lookout duties" exclusion.

**EDIT:** *The paragraph below relates to the original version of the question which discussed whether the OP would be able to take a course in culinary arts for a cruise ship, this may nor may not be relevant any more but since it was originally asked I'll leave it in for now.*

As to whether it would affect your ability to take a *course* training to be a ship's chef I imagine that would come down to the individual course requirements, if the course included time spent on placement on ships then the same health criteria as working for the company operating the ship would likely apply. This would have to be a question for the operator of any such course though. It does beg the question though as to why you'd *want* to take such a course if you couldn't progress on to having the actual job the course was intended for?